# strpos remove text/html

Tags: php, xml, parsing, substr, strpos

I'm parsing an XML file, the creators of it stuck in a bunch social media info which is completely useless to me.  I'd like to remove it before inserting the data into the db.

Problem is that its not all the same, some occurrences are :

`Be a Social Butterfly! Connect & Learn More Below:
Website • Facebook • Yelp`

Some have more social sites listed and some have less.  Id really like to remove that entire part.  also this is a vardump after running strip_tags.  The original looks like this:

```
<strong>Be a Social Butterfly! Connect & Learn More Below:</br></strong>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.kiran-indian.com">Website</a> •<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Kiran-Indian-Cuisine/55785994435"> Facebook</a> • <a target="_blank" href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/kiran-indian-cuisine-new-york">Yelp</a>
```

I used preg_replace to get rid of th entire sentence "be a social butterfly...." with

```
$description = strip_tags(preg_replace('/\bBe a Social Butterfly! Connect & Learn More Below\b/', '', $value['redemptionLocations']['description']));
```

A buddy of mine suggested the use of strpos to find first/last parts and substr to remove everything in between, but sadly I am not advanced  enough to figure out how to do that.

Thanks in advance!

description field:

```
       
Food always does one thing. It helps keep you alive. But it can do more. It can be an experience that educates, transports, and invigorates you. Lunch or dinner at <a target="_blank" href="http://www.kiran-indian.com/home.htmls">Kiran Indian Cuisine</a> a lot more than a chance to keep from starving for another day --- it’s a chance to depart from the norm with delicious homemade dishes using the freshest of ingredients and the most aromatic seasoning available. They are open 7 days a week from 11 a.m. to 11 p.m. and accept all the major credit cards, plus when you order online from the surrounding area, delivery is 100% free of charge.</br></br>

<strong>Be a Social Butterfly! Connect & Learn More Below:</br></strong>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.kiran-indian.com">Website</a> •<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/pages/Kiran-Indian-Cuisine/55785994435"> Facebook</a> •  <a target="_blank" href="http://www.yelp.com/biz/kiran-indian-cuisine-new-york">Yelp</a>
```

seems pasting that code into here automatically adjusts asci/etc.

Comment: You want to remove the site listed after that sentences of "..Butterfly..", regardless of the number of sites?

Comment: yes, remove everything from that sentence until the end which is </description>.  I'm just not sure how that works since its technically parsing all the info inside of <description>

Comment: Then the format is something like: <description>Be a Social Butterfly!.. list of sites</description>, ryt?

Comment: Can we see what the feed looks like?

Comment: social butterfly part is just the last part of the <description>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the position of the first string in the whole text, use `strpos` for that, then you need to find the position at the end of the chunk you want to remove, again use `strpos`.  Now you have the beginning and end point of the chunk you want to remove, use `substr_replace` to replace it with nothing `''`. `substr_replace` takes the length of the chunk to remove as the 4th parameter, rather than the position as with the 3rd parameter, so you need to subtract the 1st position int from the 2nd position int to figure out the length.

```
$feedtext='<description> this part is important...  be a social butterfly .. blah blah etc etc whatever whatever </description>';

$pos1=strpos($feedtext,'be a social butterfly');
$pos2=strpos($feedtext,'</description>');
$len=$pos2-$pos1;
$newtext=substr_replace($feedtext,'',$pos1,$len);

echo $newtext;
```

tested: http://www.ideone.com/1X5gI

Comment: I tried the above code, i replaced $feedtext with $feedtext = $value['redemptionLocations']['description'], it output everything inside of <description>

Comment: @mike you're probably going to need to change the stuff being looked for in the pos1 and pos2 variables (they are case sensitive). The code works, I linked to a working example.  If it's not working, it's because the strings you're trying to get the position of aren't in the haystack you're passing to it.

Comment: does this work on asci characters? I am trying to set pos1 as '&lt;strong&gt;Be a Social Butterfly' and pos2 as '&lt;/a&gt;'

Comment: If that is exactly how it is in the string you're providing ($feedtext) then yes that will work fine.

Comment: is it possible to make strpos goto the absolute end without defining a particular set of characters?

Comment: Ya, change the $len line to `$len=strlen($feedtext) - $pos1;`